# No more access to user login

Tags: 8

The URL *mysite.com/user/login* redirects to home page, so that I've lost access to administration.

I tried *mysite.com/?q=user/login*. Sadly, same redirection. :-(

Has anyone encountered this probleme or any idea ? Thanks :-)

Comment: Welcome on Drupal Answers ;) Are you maybe using a module for redirections after login like for example: redirect_after_login?

Comment: @zanvidmar Should not that module redirect users after they are logged in?

Comment: @amuli Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not clear if you aren't able to log in because you are redirected before you could log in, or you are already logged in and you are trying to access your user profile but you are redirected to the front page. Which one is your case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers :-) Indeed, it's impossible to log in because **mysite/user/login** is rewritten into **mysite/historique**. The error I made two days ago : in _Configuration > System_, I added **/historique** to the base URL. I guess I need to correct my mistake by writing in the MySQL DB (if this config parameter is indeed in the DB).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting a question on Drupal Answers. Do you have access to your site via any CLI tool (Drush or Drupal Console) maybe? That would fundamentally widen the range of your opportunities for rescue.

Comment: @Balu Ertl Thank you for this suggestion. But I have no experience with Drush (sure that misfortune will encourage me to now jump into Drush), and I made the error on the production server (in fact, I confused that " base URL " config parameter with " default page ").